# propensity score matching in MatchIt package in linux

Tags: r, linux

Actually, I have some difficulty to do propensity score matching in MatchIt package in Linux:

1. I do not know how to load the MatchIt package after I install it in R in Vnc Viewer,if I input "R" then press "ENTER" first in the home directory, then I input >library(MatchIt) >q(), then press "ENTER" last ,is it the right way to load the MatchIt package?

Alternatively, I typed "R -e 'library("MatchIt")'", then "ENTER" directly in the home directory, it can load successfully?

2. how could I write a script to run to do propensity score matching after loading MatchIt?

I typed "Rscripts xxx.R", but things seem to be not working, so what should I do correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console, type R and you should be taken to an R session. This is an interactive session which is not ideal for writing scripts. My suggestion would be to write your script (`library()`, import of data...) into a text file and source that, e.g. `Rscript sourcefile.R`. Or, use an IDE which will enable you to write code, run it and a few other trinkets. There are a few options out there, RStudio appears to be quite popular and comes in a desktop and server versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I followed your suggestion and read my data with a script by source "Rscript sourcefile.R" successfully.

Comment: In details,first,I installed the package "MatchIt" in R console,the screen showed that "The downloaded sources packages are in '/tmp/....a directory../' ",then I typed q() and y .Second,I type R and taken to an R session,the I typed "library(MatchIt)"(or I typed require(MatchIt),it showed  loading required package:MatchIt),then I typed q() and y.Last,I sourced Rscript sourcefile.R,but there were something wrong like "could not find function "MatchIt"",so what's wrong with it?If I failed to install or load the package,or anything else wrong.Waitting for your reply,Thanks.

Comment: You appear to be using a function named `MatchIt` somewhere in your code. The function in the package you should be calling is `matchit` (notice the case).